# How to install sparse_dot_topn using Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I am trying to install string-grouper which has a dependency on sparse_dot_topn. I am running Windows and when I try to do a pip install, I get an error message. Googling around looks like sparse_dot_topn requires to be compiled using C++, but I cannot find any documentation about it. Have anyone installed this module in Windows without Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the C++ tools from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) and you should be able to build `sparse_dot_topn`. I was able to successfully `pip install string-grouper` after this.

Comment: Thanks for contributing this answer! Can you elaborate a tiny bit about _how_ installing the Visual C++ build tools solves the problem? I suspect that the VC++ installer puts the tools in a 'known location' such that `pip install` finds them automatically, but I'm not certain this is true—can you confirm? (I submitted an edit for your post that states this in a more explicit way, please correct it if you feel I've said something wrong.)